# issues when using for loops and arrays to shorten my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
async for submission in subreddit.top(subreddit):
    if await client.memeCollection.find_one({'url': submission.url}):
        print('Found already posted submission')
        continue
    else:
        await client.memeCollection.insert_one({'subreddit': str(submission.subreddit), 'url': submission.url})

async for submission in subreddit1.top("day"):
    if await client.memeCollection.find_one({'url': submission.url}):
        print('Found already posted submission')
        continue
    else:
        await client.memeCollection.insert_one({'subreddit': str(submission.subreddit), 'url': submission.url})
async for submission in subreddit2.top("day"):
    if await client.memeCollection.find_one({'url': submission.url}):
        print('Found already posted submission')
        continue
    else:
        await client.memeCollection.insert_one({'subreddit': str(submission.subreddit), 'url': submission.url})
async for submission in subreddit3.top("day"):
    if await client.memeCollection.find_one({'url': submission.url}):
        print('Found already posted submission')
        continue
    else:
        await client.memeCollection.insert_one({'subreddit': str(submission.subreddit), 'url': submission.url})
```

This is my current method of downloading memes for selected subredits, I have different variables called `subreddit1`-`subreddit4` with different subreddits in each one,

For each variable I have a `for` loop.

I tried to put all of the values into arrays, but subreddit doesn't have a `.top` when it's an array, so I'm not sure how else I can get around this.

```
    subreddit = ['memes', 'dankmemes', 'AdviceAnimals', 'MemeEconomy', 'ComedyCemetery', 'PrequelMemes',
             'terriblefacebookmemes', 'PewdiepieSubmissions']

async for submission in subreddit.top(subreddit):
    if await client.memeCollection.find_one({'url': submission.url}):
        print('Found already posted submission')
        continue
    else:
        await client.memeCollection.insert_one({'subreddit': str(submission.subreddit), 'url': submission.url})
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use a simple loop before it?*

```
 topics = ['memes', 'dankmemes', 'AdviceAnimals', 'MemeEconomy', 'ComedyCemetery', 'PrequelMemes',
         'terriblefacebookmemes', 'PewdiepieSubmissions']
for topic in topics:  # <-- normal loop here 
    async for submission in subreddit.top(topics):
        if await client.memeCollection.find_one({'url': submission.url}):
            print(f'Found already posted submission {topic}')
        else:
            await client.memeCollection.insert_one({'subreddit': str(submission.subreddit), 'url': submission.url})
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unsure how to do that due to subreddit being undefined.

I can either set subreddit to an array, or a one string variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
subredditList = ['memes', 'dankmemes', 'AdviceAnimals', 'MemeEconomy', 'ComedyCemetery', 'PrequelMemes',
                 'terriblefacebookmemes', 'PewdiepieSubmissions']

newSublist = [await reddit.subreddit(x) for x in subredditList]
print(newSublist)

for x in newSublist:
    async for submission in x.top('day'):
        if await client.memeCollection.find_one({'url': submission.url}):
            print('Found already posted submission')
            continue
        else:
            await client.memeCollection.insert_one({'subreddit': str(submission.subreddit), 'url': submission.url})
```

Had to make a new list and append and then loop through that list in another loop to get the top, thanks for the guidance!